# Chained class methods throw "not a function" error

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I was trying to do an exercise for chaining function in JS classes. I ran into some issues where the name of the function is producing some weird error.

Basically,

```
const user = User.init();
user.name().first_name("Alice").last_name("Bob");
```

with function

```
class User
{

static init()
{
    return new User();
}

constructor()
{
    this.firstname = "";
    this.lastname = "";
    this.dob = "";
    this.unit = "";
    this.street = "";
    this.suburb = "";
    this.state = "";
    this.postcode = "";
}

name()
{
    console.log("lol this is name");
    return this;
}

first_name(firstname)
{
    console.log("Setting firstname");
    return this;
}

last_name(lastname)
{
    console.log("Setting lastname");
    return this;
}
}
```

produces an error, however,

```
const user = User.init();
user.name().firstname("Alice").lastname("Bob");
```

with function

```
class User
{

static init()
{
    return new User();
}

constructor()
{
    this.firstname = "";
    this.lastname = "";
    this.dob = "";
    this.unit = "";
    this.street = "";
    this.suburb = "";
    this.state = "";
    this.postcode = "";
}

name()
{
    console.log("lol this is name");
    return this;
}

firstname(firstname)
{
    console.log("Setting firstname");
    return this;
}

lastname(lastname)
{
    console.log("Setting lastname");
    return this;
}
}
```

does not.

Error message

```
user.name().firstname("Alice").lastname("Bob");
        ^

TypeError: user.name(...).firstname is not a function
```

Both of these method is the same except for the underscore on the function name. Is someone out there kindly tell me what is the error. Thanks !

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. This is my first post and I am not sure how this would look like in a post. I have edited the post. Thanks !

Comment: Your first code does not have a `firstname` method. The method name in the first code is `first_name`, thus the typeerror.

Comment: Please make sure we can reproduce the problem. What you posted is not executable code. If I just wrap this in `class User { ... }` and try `new User().name().firstname("Alice").lastname("Bob");`, I am _not_ getting any error.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I think i figured out the issue. The this.firstname is causing the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `User.init()` calls `new User()`. This will create a new `User` object, whose `firstname` is inherited from the class prototype as your "Setting firstname" function, and then promptly overshadow it by setting `this.firstname = ""`.

In the second example you don't do `this.first_name = ""`, and the object remains functional.

In general, you should decide which properties are methods and which properties are data - you can't use one property for both.

(Note that this also illustrates the importance of proper context - there was near-zero chance of diagnosing this from the code snippet you first posted :) )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that I cannot have same variable name and function name. This is my first post and I just figured how to post this correctly. hahaha This community sure answer question fast. Cheers.